# How to get maven-bundle-plugin to include maven dependencies in OSGi manifest <Import-Package>

Tags: dependencies, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

Hoping someone can help me with this problem.  I'm trying to use the maven-bundle-plugin to automatically generate my OSGi manifest, from my maven dependencies.  Some dependencies I'm installing in the OSGi container, since they're shared across multiple bundles.  For example, Spring.  I'm setting the scope of these dependencies, as provided (since they're provided within the container, rather than being embedded).  However, I'm unable to get the maven-bundle-plugin to include these dependencies within the  section  of the manifest.  Any ideas how to do this?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.osgi.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-mvc-bundle</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.osgi.version>1.2.1</spring.osgi.version>
</properties>

<!-- Module dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies here... -->
</dependencies>

<!-- Build plugins + config -->
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                    <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Aren't you archiving with the standard archiver instead of the bundle plugin? Did you follow the instructions at the bundle plugin page?

Answer (score 0):

Well this strongly depends on your usage of those dependencies. If they are used with dynamic Classloading the bnd tool doesn't know how to handle those. So you need to add those dependencies to a  section of your configuration part. This way those are added to your Manifest as Imports in addition to the already found Imports.